# Guess a number python issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a problem with this script, but I see nothing wrong with it, can anyone help?

```
import random
selected_number=random.randint(1,100)
print('The number is between %d and %d') % (selected_number - selected_number / 5, selected_number + selected_number / 5)
def guess():
    number_input=raw_input()
    if number_input > selected_number:
        print('Lower...')
        guess()
    if number_input < selected_number:
        print('Higher...')
        guess()
    if number_input == selected_number:
        print('Correct')
        guess()
guess()
```

Comment: You're not comparing int to int. You are comparing str to int. Cast your `raw_input` to int => `int(raw_input())`

Comment: change (raw_input()) to int(raw_input())

Comment: Consider `input()` instead of `raw_input()`, or converting it to int using `int(raw_input())`

Comment: @YotamSalmon No. If they are using Python 2, they *absolutely* want to use `raw_input` and not `input`. Python 3 does not have `raw_input`, so the OP would have had other problems.

Comment: There seems to be debate about what version of Python you are using. Please clarify, as the solutions being provided are misleading.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody's pointed out yet that "*I'm having a problem*" is never enough information, especially if you "*see nothing wrong with it*".

Comment: I am using Python 2. `int(raw_input())` worked for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 2 :

```
number_input = input()
```

For Python 3 :

```
number_input = int(input())
```